# How do I change value of an array to another value based on a different array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that has an id and type value (`{ id: '23', kind: 'apple' }, { id: '35', kind: broccoli }`), but I have a function that requires a name for the id (pretend id 23 means fruits and id 35 means vegetables), such as 'fruits' or 'vegetables'. I write out a different array that has the id and the name for the id (`{ id: '23', type: 'fruit' }, { id: '35', type: 'vegetable' }`). How can I filter the first array so that I change the id from saying 23 or 35 to saying fruit or vegetable?

Comment: I could use an if else statement or a switch case statement, but there has to be an easier way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` to change the value of the id on the first array by looking up that id in a hash table.

#### hash table:

```
idHash = {'23': 'fruit', '35': 'vegetable'}
```

so that `idHash['23']` returns `"fruit"`

#### Array#map

```
array = [{id: '23', kind:'apple'},{id: '35', kind:'broccoli'}]
array = array.map(function(item){
  item.id = idHash[item.id] //Lookup the 'type' fromt he hash table
  return item
})

console.log(array)
```

outputs `[{"id":"fruit","kind":"apple"},{"id":"vegetable","kind":"broccoli"}]`